# How can i change the dictionary output format in python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, key, data-science

I am getting output in this format
[image]
But I want output in this format
[image]

Any Help will be appreciated
Thankyou in Advance

I've tried to convert my data into an array but it doesn't work as i want

This is my output :

{'date': '2021-12-30 17:31:05.865139', 'sub_data': [{'key': 'day0', 'value': 255}, {'key': 'day1', 'value': 1}, {'key': 'day3', 'value': 8}, {'key': 'day7', 'value': 2}, {'key': 'day15', 'value': 3}, {'key': 'day30', 'value': 5}]}

{'date': '2021-12-31 17:31:05.907697', 'sub_data': [{'key': 'day0', 'value': 222}, {'key': 'day1', 'value': 1}, {'key': 'day3', 'value': 0}, {'key': 'day7', 'value': 0}, {'key': 'day15', 'value': 1}, {'key': 'day30', 'value': 0}]}]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can generate a pandas dataframe the way you want. The output data you provide is very nested and you have to pull out data. A problem is, that in the sub-set data the dictionary keys are called 'key" and not the actual name. With a custom function you can prepare the data as needed:

**Option I:**

```
def generate_dataframe(dataset):

    # Init empty DataFrame - bad practice
    df_result = pd.DataFrame()

    for data in dataset:

        dataframe_row = {}

        # Convert date
        date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(data['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        dataframe_row['date'] = date_time_obj.strftime("%d%b%y")

        for vals in data['sub_data']:
            
            dataframe_row[vals['key']] = vals['value']
            
        df_result = df_result.append(dataframe_row, ignore_index=True)
        return df_result

dataset =[output_I,output_II]

df = generate_dataframe(dataset)
```

**Option II**:
Extract data and transpose sub data

```
def process_sub_data(data):

# convert subdate to dataframe first
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data['sub_data'])

# Transpose dataframe
df_data = df_data.T

# Make first row to column
df_data.columns = df_data.iloc[0]
df_data = df_data.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Option III**
You can try to format nested data with

```
df_res = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=2)
```

This will not work properly as your column names (day1, ... day30) are not the keys of the dict

Hope I could help :)